# Many apache2 process getting created and server is coming to halt

Tags: apache-2.2, rackspace-cloud

We have purchased a 20 Gb and 512 MB ram box from rackspace. We have installed apache2, php5 and mysql to run a website (shopping site). The problem from last 4 days is that after some requests the apache process are multiplying and the server is coming to halt (not responding). To test the number of requests we tried `siege -c25 -t1M  www.styleos.com` and after 10 request we get `Connection time out` .

Can anyone tell whats the problem.

Comment: Can you check what your memory usage looks like once you hit those 10 clients and provide the output of `vmstat` here? Also what's the output of `free -m` at that point as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was not with the server. The problem was with the code.

Answer (score 0):

What are you seeing in /var/log/apache2/*error.log.

Are you seeing "server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting"

Comment: No... nothing like that in error.log